# Mobile project with Phonegap

Tags: mobile, cordova

I've developed one project one year ago using Phonegap, it was there very promising technology,
but as I can see now it is not so popular today.
I know pros and cons of Phonegap, what I wanted to ask if this technology going to "die" or it still worth to work with it.

Comment: [Here's the best answer you're going to get](http://www.magicmgmt.com/gary/magic8ball/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one knows the future, but i can surely ensure you that it won't die in a near future, and here are the reasons i think of:

- Many frameworks used for mobile development such as `Sencha Touch`, `jQuery-Mobile` deppend on phonegap for native features;
- The lags/conflicts that phonegap had together with jQuery-mobile are getting better each day, each release;
- The fast development is something many companies search, at my work (software development company) each time there are more and more costumers looking for a fast and cheaper development for some mobile apps;
- Mobile device's performance are growing exponencial, wich may grant a big future on non-native apps

From my point of view, phonegap development is perfect, as long as you are not looking for the biggest performance, or very large applications

Comment: Yep it is, still don't forget that native development will always have better performance